# JavaScript function declaration difference

Tags: javascript, function, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

What's the difference in declaration of this functions i know example one is the normal way to do it, why we need two and three?

```
function one(var1,var2) {
   alert("inside functtion one");
}

two = function (var1,var2) {
   alert("inside function two");
}

var three = function (var1,var2) {
   alert("inside function three");
}
```

Comment: three and one are (for this example) identical.. two messes with the scope?? attaches it to the window object iirc?

Comment: Check out: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/

Comment: @rlemon three and one are subtly different in that you can call one before its declaration, but you can't call three until after its assignment. Also one is a named function while three is anonymous, but you can work around that.

Comment: after three is declared does it not function the same as a named function... i.e.i can call it the same and there is no wonky IE memory issues.

Comment: as per the first part of your comment... TBH I did not know that, good to know though :P

Answer (score 0):

The first and the third are just two ways to declare a function which exists globally in the scope chain. The middle is attaching the function `two` to the window object and allowing it to exist there.

```
console.log(window.one); // undefined
console.log(window.two);
console.log(window.three); // undefined
```

Comment: note: this is only **one** difference. depending on the context you are asking your question in closures have a lot to do with it. where are these declarations happening?

Comment: its script run in header of page in header

Comment: and that makes what difference? Not where in the document, where relative to the rest of the javascript code. is it in a closure?